# Install gem pg -v '1.4.6' in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Am having some issues with " An error occurred while installing pg (1.4.6), and Bundler cannot continue." in my rails application , can anyone please help me solve this error

I tried running bundle install command terminal but it failed along the install of 'pg'

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace of the error.